# UIImageView Fading based on ScrollView Position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIPageControl` that flips through different pages. I'd like to have a UIImageView begin to fade as the user scrolls from page 1 to page 2. I'm struggling trying to figure out the proper way to add a layer based on the position. Any help would be most appreciated...

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade out" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; // some how based on position?? 
    imageView.alpha = 1.0; // here to?
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

**Edit:**

Set the delegate:

```
 self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: Use an NSTimer that checks the position of the UIScrollView every frame and updated the alpha value, then invalidate the timer after the alpha value is 0.

Answer (score 9):

You need the delegate to override the following method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Then you should check against the `scrollView.contentOffset.x` value to determine how much the scroll view has scrolled horizontally, and use it to determine your imageView's alpha as follows:

```
CGFloat newAlpha = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width; // This will need to be adapted depending on the content size of your scroll view -- do not just copy and paste this expecting it to work :)
imageView.alpha = newAlpha;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm using a UIPageController and UIPageControl, and when I add this method to my .m it doesn't seem to ever get called. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @BobYousuk Did you set up the UIPageController delegate?

Comment: @icodebuster yes using the code in the edited question above. Any other ideas?

Comment: @BobYousuk Do this `self.pageController.delegate = self;`